# Perm Denied, when trying to copy files from flash drive

Tags: retropie

I am running retro pie On a Raspberry Pi 2 and I am new to the Linux, So please somebody tell me what I am doing wrong here

1. I have a file, `gba_Bios.bin` on a flash drive on `/usb/`
2. I do `cp media/usb0/gba_bios.bin/opt/retropie/emulators/gpsp/raspberrypi`
3. I get a response telling me that access is denied
4. Or I do it a bit different way and I mess up the **dir** and it says no such directory.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo`. you forgot `sudo`. Root permission is required if you're going to write into the `/opt` directory.

`sudo cp /media/usb0/gba_bios.bin /opt/retropie/emulators/gpsp/raspberrypi`

Make sure the file actually exists. As in `/media/usb0` is actually the correct folder where `gba_bios.bin` is. Flash drives are sometimes not mounted automatically on plugin.

Comment: `sudo` is not necessarily the problem here. There could be a couple issues, the most obvious is that he's using `cp` incorrectly. Another issue may be that the permissions of the hosted file or destination directory are incorrectly set for this command. `sudo` is a valid way to deal with such an issue, but you should explain what it's doing, and how to check such things. At the very least, explain your correction to his `cp` command, please.

Comment: @Jacobm001 I was still editing my answer and accidentally hit post. Also, I'm pretty sure you need `sudo` to write to `/opt`.

Comment: @Jacobm001 Also, he used `cp` correctly. Probably bad formatting and incorrect copy-pasting led to it lacking a space and a `/` at the beginning. Second point is, as I have already mentioned, `sudo` is required to write into `/opt`.

Comment: @Jacobm001 Third point is, `cp` will show `cannot stat` first before `permission denied`. So his question implies that the file does exist, and writing is the issue. I'm not quite sure if you're aware of that. Anyways, added explanation :)

Comment: btw I got all of these commands from another post here on stack- and he told me to do that so me being ignorant to Linux I just typed it in

Comment: @PandaLion98: fair enough +1

Comment: im trying it right now.

Comment: @TylerTotally Hey, wait a sec. You sure SR1127 provided the correct solution? The official documentation says otherwise: https://github.com/retropie/RetroPie-Setup/wiki/Game-Boy-Advance

Comment: No There was no documentation as I recall

Comment: @TylerTotally Well there it is.

Comment: @PandaLion98 Thank you very much for helping I have my raspberry pi on my Workbench trying to get this working

Comment: @PandaLion98 It told me "cd: missing destination file operand after" then the Long directory. When I check /opt/retropie/emulators/gpsp It told me that its there but its highlighted in red

Comment: @TylerTotally Use. The. Official. Documentation. Here's a tutorial if you want: https://weekendengineer.wordpress.com/2014/09/08/setting-up-gameboy-advance-for-retropie/